# Expose ddev web port to network

Tags: ddev

I just updated ddev to 1.10.2 from 1.8.0 and now my environment isn't accessible on our network anymore. I checked the release notes and see it's a security change. However, as we're on a secure network and I want to share my environment with my colleagues I want the old situation back.

The release notes say `you can override the settings with a docker-compose.letthemin.yaml`. My question is: How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious technique is to use the `ddev share` command, which is explicit sharing using ngrok, and works outside your local network as well.

But if you want to expose a web project on your local network, use this technique:

.ddev/docker-compose.letthemin.yaml:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  web:
    ports:
    - "80"
    - "443"
```

use `ddev describe` to find out the http URL. Let's say it's http://127.0.0.1:32859. On other hosts on your network you'd use http://:32859 to access it.

I don't think this works with the `host_webserver_port` or `host_https_port` configuration options, so the port would change every time you do a `ddev restart`.

Comment: I was afraid those were my only options. Neither of these is ideal. It would have been ideal if this new 'feature' was optional. I understand if you're on a public network you don't want the environment accessible, but on a secure company network it should still be possible without workarounds. I'll use the second option for now and report this as a bug. Thanks.

Comment: There's another lovely and very creative option offered in https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/1794#issuecomment-521402633 - Basically use ddev-router as an add-on service and leave it open to the world.